# Installing RPMs on system with no internet causes dependency conflicts: libstdc++.so.6, libm, etc

Tags: centos, rpm, chroot, dependencies, glibc

To avoid the XY problem, let me first describe the situation.

We have a client project of unique circumstances. We have a relatively modern software stack (Keras DNN stuff) that needs to run on a client's system. This system, a Cloudera CentOS 6 cluster, in production, is airgapped for security. We can't guarantee this thing has ever seen the internet, ever.

We developed a bash script which installs the requisite packages from disk using RPM and tested on our local simulated (containerized) cluster (YUM fails because the repo database is not up to date). After some fiddling, we were able to get Keras running without so much as a packet from the internet.

The client has his own virtualized system set up which is supposed to be pretty close to the actual cluster (in terms of config). When he ran it, however, total catastrophe. Lots of errors like:

(for installing glibc-common-2.12 and friends via 
`sudo rpm -Uvh glibc-common-2.12-1.209.el6_9.1.x86_64.rpm  glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.1.x86_64.rpm glibc-headers-2.12-1.209.el6_9.1.x86_64.rpm glibc-devel-2.12-1.209.el6_9.1.x86_64.rpm`
)

```
warning: ./rpm/glibc-common-2.12-1.209.el6_9.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies
    tzdata >= 2015g-4 is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.209.el6_9.1.x86_64.rpm
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.13)(64bit) is needed by (installed) util-linux-2.23.2-26.el7.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.13)(64bit) is needed by (installed) systemd-219-19.el7.x86_64
    ...(more of the same)...
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.13)(64bit) is needed by (installed) xz-libs-5.1.2-12alpha.el17.x86_64
```

(Or running the command: `sudo rpm -Uvh gcc-c++-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64.rpm gcc-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64.rpm libstdc++-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64.rpm libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64.rpm` )

```
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) is needed by (installed) {name of a package}
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) is needed by (installed) {name of another package}
...
```

X is needed by Y is the most common error, but we also see ones like

```
openssl < 1:1.0.1-0.3.beta3 is obsoleted by (installed) openssl-libs-1:1.0.1e-42.el4.9x86_64
```

and

```
file /etc/rpm/macros.ghc-srpm from install of epel-release-6-8.noarch conflicts with file from package redhad-rpm-config-9.1.0-68.el7.centos.noarch
```

In particular, a lot of conflicts are stemming from

- libc.so.6
- libm.so.6
- libgmp.so.3
- libmpfr.so.4
- libstdc++.so.6
- libffi.so.6

which are all super crucial libraries, and I 1) can't assume any particular version will be on the cluster, and 2) can't be monkeying around with, lest one of them breaks.

I'm more of a machine learning CS and my linux skills are enough to set up and service CUDA boxes and such, but this is starting to be deep water for me, so any input, even simple stuff, is appreciated. Is there any way to create a separate library environment where we can install the necessary deps without disturbing the ones already there? I know `chroot` is a thing but I have no idea how to properly wield it.

**tl;dr - dependency hell on an airgapped system with no remote admin ability and a crusty old, poorly-maintained build.**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have to work in airgapped environments very often.

The best approach I have found so far is to have a virtual machine with EXACTLY the same environment (i.e. exactly the same version for all packages, if possible with its installation following the same process used for the production environment) - give that VM internet access, and use the appropriate package manager to DOWNLOAD ONLY all required packages.

To download only packages and not install them, I use:

```
yum install --downloadonly <requiredpackage>
```

This works out of the box at least with CentOS 6 - in other RPM based distribution you may need to install the *yum-downloadonly* package, as this functionality is provided by a yum plug-in.

Then, I archive all the downloaded packages in a .tar.gz file, transfer that archive to the production system, decompress in a temporary directory and install packages using:

```
rpm -i <directory>/*.rpm
```

It is also important to use point releases instead of only the major CentOS version or the "$releaseversion" variable in the /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo configuration files, as the repositories with major version get updates over time. This point release shall match the installed version on the VM used for downloading and on the airgapped system.

For example, use:

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/
```

instead of

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/
```

as the latter will have packages updates until CentOS 7 reaches its end of maintenance (November 30, 2020 - according to [the CentOS FAQ](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-fe8a0be91ee3e7dea812e8694491e1dde5b75e6d)) .

From the description you made, it seems that the virtual machine you mention has been somehow updated from the CentOS repositories, so you're having some version dependency conflicts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `downloadonly` and `rpm -i` is exactly how the script runs currently.

> From the description you made, it seems that the virtual machine you mention has been somehow updated from the CentOS repositories, so you're having some version dependency conflicts.

I'm glad you mentioned this, as I suspected exactly this, but not enough confidence or know-how to do anything about it. But I'll investigate this deeper.

Comment: If you can, and have some time to spend on this, try to install a new fresh VM following the original process used to install the production server, and test the installation wihout internet access on that machine.

Comment: Also, note you're trying to install _-Uvh glibc-common-2.12-1.209.el6_9.1.x86_64.rpm_ and the RPM system says _libc.so.6(**GLIBC_2.13**)(64bit) is needed by (installed) util-linux-2.23.2-26.el7.x86_64_

Comment: The blank Cloudera VM downloads GLIBC_2.12 when I call that dependency (with zero yum updates). I highly suspect now that the Client's laptop is running something updated. 

We have a yum debug dump now though so we should be able to back-track and figure out the exact production build.

Comment: Run `rpm -qav` on both environments and check for differences

Comment: How do you get out of dependency hell? I do this often but even with downloadonly, I find that trying to install in airgapped systems I'm ALWAYS missing a dependency.

Comment: In the VM used to download packages to be installed in the isolated environment it is also necessary to use  point release repositories instead of a major version - that is, using "7.7.1908" instead of just "7" or $releasever in the repo configuration for yum. That point release has to match the installed version on the airgapped server.